# Redrawing buttons and other widgets in Kivy language

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to write a game similar to Who wants to be a millionaire using Kivy language. I am having problem with dynamic feature of widgets.

What I want to do is when the user clicks to an option button to select an answer, the button remains in down state for a while and then switches color depending on correct answer. Then same screen should update and give me new question with all colors have been reset. Here are related part of the code I am working on. Ignore the fact that I have two question builders, I will switch to random question generator once I make sure this one is working.

```
class PlayScreen(Screen):
    question = StringProperty()
    question_id = StringProperty()
    option_a = StringProperty()
    option_b = StringProperty()
    option_c = StringProperty()
    option_d = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PlayScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Questions = dict([('id12345', "What is the capital city of Azerbaijan"), ('idd5', "What is the capital city of Turkey")])
        self.Answer_Set = dict([('id12345', ["Ganja", "Baku", "Lankaran", "Ghakh"]), ('idd5', ["Istanbul", "Tiflis", "Ankara", "Izmir"])])
        self.Correct_Answers = dict([('id12345', "Baku"), ('idd5', "Ankara")])
        self.Question_IDs = list(self.Questions.keys())

        self.question_builder()


    def question_builder(self):
        self.question_id  =self.Question_IDs[0]   #randint(0, len(self.Questions))
        self.question = self.Questions[self.question_id]
        self.option_a = self.Answer_Set[self.question_id][0]
        self.option_b = self.Answer_Set[self.question_id][1]
        self.option_c = self.Answer_Set[self.question_id][2]
        self.option_d = self.Answer_Set[self.question_id][3]
        return self.question

    def question_builder_2(self):
        self.question_id  =self.Question_IDs[1]   #randint(0, len(self.Questions))
        self.question = self.Questions[self.question_id]
        self.option_a = self.Answer_Set[self.question_id][0]
        self.option_b = self.Answer_Set[self.question_id][1]
        self.option_c = self.Answer_Set[self.question_id][2]
        self.option_d = self.Answer_Set[self.question_id][3]
        return self.question

    def checker(self, instance, question_id):
        if instance.text == self.Correct_Answers[question_id]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

Kivy_language_body = """
<PlayScreen>:
    name: "play"
    GridLayout:
        question: root.question
        question_id: root.question_id
        option_a: root.option_a
        option_b: root.option_b
        option_c: root.option_c
        option_d: root.option_d
        default_color: root.default_color

        id: PlayScreenGrid
        cols:1
        rows: 2
        GridLayout:
            id: q
            cols: 1
            rows: 1
            size: root.width, root.height/2
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "top":1}
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1,0,0
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Label:
                text: PlayScreenGrid.question
                font_size: 20

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 2
            size: root.width, root.height/2
            pos_hint: {"y":0}

            Button:
                id: a
                text: root.option_a
                font_size: 20
                min_state_time: 4

                on_release:
                    a.background_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
                    self.trigger_action(duration=5)
                    self.state = "down"
                    print (self.state)
                    self.state = "normal"
                    print(self.state)
                    if root.checker(a, root.question_id): a.background_color = 1,1,0,1
                    else: a.background_color = 100,0,0,0.5
                    self.parent._trigger_layout()
                    root.question_builder_2()


            Button:
                id: b
                text: root.option_b
                font_size: 20
                on_release:
                    self.state = "down"
                    self.state = app.timer()
                    if root.checker(b, root.question_id): b.background_color = 1,1,0,1
                    else: b.background_color = 100,0,0,0.5



            Button:
                id: c
                text: root.option_c
                font_size: 20
                on_release:
                    self.state = "down"
                    app.timer()
                    self.state = "normal"
                    if root.checker(c, root.question_id): c.background_color = 1,1,0,1
                    else: c.background_color = 100,0,0,0.5
                    app.timer()
                    c.background_color = 1,1,1,1
                    app.timer()
                    if root.checker(c, root.question_id): root.question_builder_2()

            Button:
                id: d
                text: root.option_d
                font_size: 20
                on_release:
                    self.state = "down"
                    app.timer()
                    self.state = "normal"
                    if root.checker(d, root.question_id): d.background_color = 1,1,0,1
                    else: d.background_color = 100,0,0,0.5
                    app.timer()
                    d.background_color = 1,1,1,1
                    app.timer()
                    if root.checker(d, root.question_id):
root.question_builder_2()
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly solution for the problem I stated above

```
class Countdown(Label):
a = NumericProperty(1)  # seconds for button to remain in down state before the answer is revealed
b = NumericProperty(0.5) # seconds for button to remain in red or green color after answer is revealed before the next action

def __init__(self, instance, background_color, correct):
    super(Countdown, self).__init__()
    self.intance = instance
    self.background_color = background_color
    self.correct = correct

def start(self,):
    Animation.cancel_all(self)  # stop any current animations
    self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)
    self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.finish_callback)
    self.anim.start(self)

def start_2(self):
    self.anime = Animation(a=0, duration=self.b)
    self.anime.bind(on_complete=self.open_popup)
    self.anime.start(self)

def finish_callback(self, animation, incr_crude_clock):
    self.instance.background_color = self.background_color  # color based on answer
    self.start_2()

def open_popup(self, animation, incr_crude_clock):
    if self.correct:
        Factory.CorrectPopup().open()   # custom popup appears if answered correctly
    else:
        Factory.WrongPopup().open()     # custom popup appears if answered wrong

def on_a(self, instance, value):
    self.instance.state = "down"
    for button in self.instance.parent.children:    # disable all other buttons to prevent user from clicking them randomly
        if hasattr(button, 'id'):
            if button.id != self.instance.id:
                button.disabled = True
# Basic grid with question and 4 answer choices:
class PlayGrid(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.clear_widgets()
        super(PlayGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.question = StringProperty()
        self.id = 'plygrd'

        self.cols = 1
        self.question_grid = GridLayout()
        self.answer_grid = GridLayout()
        self.answer_grid.id = 'ansgrd'
        self.button_grid = FloatLayout()

        self.answer_grid.cols = 2
        self.answer_grid.rows = 2
        self.answer_grid.size_hint = 1, 0.5
        self.answer_grid.pos_hint = {'y': 0}

        self.question_grid.size_hint = 1, 0.5
        self.question_grid.cols = 1
        self.question_grid.rows = 1
        self.question_grid.pos_hint = {'center_y': 0.5}
        self.question_grid.pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5}
        self.question_grid.pos_hint = {'top': 0.85}
        self.question_builder()
        self.question_grid.question_panel = Label(text=self.question, id=self.question_id, font_size=50,
                                              halign="center", valign='middle')
        self.question_grid.clock = Countdown(None, None, False)
        self.question_grid.add_widget(self.question_grid.question_panel)

        self.add_widget(self.button_grid)
        self.add_widget(self.question_grid)
        self.add_widget(self.answer_grid)

        self.builder()

    def builder(self):
        for i in range(4):
            setattr(self.answer_grid, 'button_'+str(i), Button(text=Answer_Set[self.question_id][i], font_size=40, id='option_'+str(i), background_color=[100, 10, 0, 0.5]))
        getattr(self.answer_grid,'button_'+str(i)).bind(on_press=self.starter)
        self.answer_grid.add_widget(getattr(self.answer_grid,'button_'+str(i)))
    def starter(self, instance):
        if instance.text == Correct_Answers[self.question_id]:
            self.calculate_score(correct=True)
            instance.parent.parent.question_grid.clock.instance = instance
            instance.parent.parent.question_grid.clock.background_color = [0,1,0,1]
            instance.parent.parent.question_grid.clock.correct = True
            instance.parent.parent.question_grid.clock.start()
        else:
            self.calculate_score(correct=False)
            instance.parent.parent.question_grid.clock.instance = instance
            instance.parent.parent.question_grid.clock.background_color = [1,0,0,1]
            instance.parent.parent.question_grid.clock.correct = False
            instance.parent.parent.question_grid.clock.start()

    def question_builder(self):
        while True:
            self.question_id = Question_IDs[randint(0, len(Question_IDs)-1)]
            if self.question_id not in _cache:
                _cache.append(self.question_id)
                break
        self.question = Questions[self.question_id]
```